# Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView when loading webview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, webview

I've never encountered this problem before, and my setup is pretty much the same as previous occasions.

The error its self is:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: 
    Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
```

I am launching a `WebView` in an XML file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/facebookWebview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using tab fragments, and the fragment that launches the xml file is like so:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfacebook, container, false);

        // allocate and instanciate webview
        WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.facebookWebview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // load fb url into it
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/urlinhere");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                Log.d("TAG", " ==> " + url);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Again, this is as I have always done it. I have commented out the bulk of this code to see if the problem is here, however it is in the XML file not the .java file.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Entire stack trace

```
09-07 09:19:06.870    1150-1150/ourpackage.com.ourpackage E/WebViewFactory﹕ Chromium WebView does not exist
09-07 09:19:06.910    1150-1150/ourpackage.com.ourpackage E/WebViewFactory﹕ Chromium WebView does not exist
09-07 09:19:06.910    1150-1150/ourpackage.com.ourpackage D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-07 09:19:06.910    1150-1150/ourpackage.com.ourpackage W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a46d70)


android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:57)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at ourpackage.com.ourpackage.FragmentTab1.onCreateView(FragmentTab1.java:22)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1701)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1063)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1448)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:57)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at ourpackage.com.ourpackage.FragmentTab1.onCreateView(FragmentTab1.java:22)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1701)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1063)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1448)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
            at com.android.webview.nullwebview.NullWebViewFactoryProvider.createWebView(NullWebViewFactoryProvider.java:41)
            at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2058)
            at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2116)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3461)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3517)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
            at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:498)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:475)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:455)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:444)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:57)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at ourpackage.com.ourpackage.FragmentTab1.onCreateView(FragmentTab1.java:22)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1701)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1063)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1448)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have checked my SDK Manager and everything is up to date in there

Comment: Please post your entire stacktrace.

Comment: @TomR. amended my post

Comment: where is the line 22?

Comment: @JohnnyAW hey, line 22 of the java file (?) is `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfacebook, container, false);` unless you mean a different line 22?

Comment: Just a quick guess, do you have INTERNET permission included in your manifest?

Comment: @TomR. I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in there, still crashing with the same error

Comment: Are you sure your project do not contains other layout folders to support multiple screen size for the same layout?

Comment: just tested your code on a default activity, and it worked, maybe try to clean the project or something...

Comment: @MohamedFadlAllah Hey, I have just started the project from scratch when I posted this - I dont think I have any other layout folders in there.

Comment: @JohnnyAW how strange. Im using android studio if that makes a difference?

Comment: @JoshBoothe please post your manifest file as well, perhaps this is related to the theme set on the Activity.

Comment: what happens if you create a new WebView and pass it to setContentView?

Comment: Try to update your code to the following View view = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity()      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))      .inflate(R.layout.tabfacebook, container, false);

Comment: @MohamedFadlAllah thanks for the suggestion - however still crashing with same error

Comment: so what if you create it dynamically, like @pskink suggested?

Comment: @JohnnyAW i'm not entirely sure how to do this - looking it up on google now

Comment: @JohnnyAW Are you by any chance running this on an emulator? make sure you are not running it on an Android Wear emulator..

Comment: @TomR. I have updated my post to include the full code. Looking at the emulator, it says: `Android 4.4W, Android Wear ARM` - im guessing then that I shouldn't be using this?

Comment: This is the problem, of course the Android Wear emulator does not support Chromium, hence the error..

Comment: @JohnnyAW apologies for the wrong mentions.. I was referring to JoshBoothe obviously, but cannot edit the comments anymore.

Comment: @TomR. thank you very much for your perseverance! And everyone else - I would never have even looked into this as the issue so thanks! I was unaware that Android Wear is just that, you 'wear' it! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Sure thing, feel free to answer your own question in case others encounter a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Tom R for the answer.

In case anybody else encounters a similar problem, check what emulator you are running.

It appears I was running the emulator for [Android Wear, more info can be found here on this if you are unaware](http://www.android.com/wear/).

It was fixed by changing this to just the standard `ARM CPU` from `Wear ARM`

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a bit. Unfortunately I'm facing the same error and stacktrace in a different environment: I have a live app and randomly get those crash reports in HockeyApp. They're distributed over a variant of devices but notably mostly Nexus devices. My app does not have a wear module or anything like this. Any ideas?

Comment: @MatthiasWenz did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @AymanMahgoub unfortunately not. The error keeps persisting and we can't track it down.

Comment: seems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732169/error-inflating-class-android-webkit-webview-happens-sporadically-in-production has explanation.