# Rare NoClassDefFoundError: android/webkit/WebViewFactory$Preloader

Tags: android, android-webview

My released app runs fine on multiple thousand devices. There is only one case where an THL device running Android 4.4 throws following stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{###/###.activity.AGBActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at ###.fragment.AGBActivityFragment.onCreateView(AGBActivityFragment.java:21)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4819)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
    at ###.activity.AGBActivity.onCreate(AGBActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/webkit/WebViewFactory$Preloader
    at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:92)
    at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2081)
    at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2076)
    at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2161)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3474)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3530)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:494)
    at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:502)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:482)
    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:471)
    ... 36 more
```

The referred line 21 in AGBActivityFragment is:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agb, container, false);
```

The unexciting layout of the fragment is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            tools:context="###.fragment.AGBActivityFragment">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_decline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/decline"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_accept"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/accept"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I guess it is a system bug as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732953/4791726). Except that this does not happen on Lollipop and it is not exactly the same error.

Is there any work around or could someone explain the cause?

Comment: Yes, looks like a system problem, not a problem with your app. WebView is not updateable on KitKat, thus it definitely can't be caused by the WebView updating issue. Does this happen only on a THL device, or there are also reports from other devices?

Comment: Yes, only occurence is on that THL device. So there is no urgent need of a fix. But it would be nice.