# WebView InflateException

Tags: java, android, android-webview

In my Activity I added Webview (nothing abnormal):

```
<WebView
        tools:context=".Activities.WebViewActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"/>
```

And in my WebViewActivity I declarated it:

```
webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

The problem is my app crashing on some android devices (saw it in Crashlytics)... I reproduced this situation on emulator and get this Log (first part):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jamhome.ru.lktsj/ru.domyland.superdom.Activities.WebViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I found good solution - create Class and use it instead basic Webview:

```
public class LollipopFixedWebView extends WebView {

    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context) {
        super(getFixedContext(context));
    }

    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs);
    }

    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public LollipopFixedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, boolean privateBrowsing) {
        super(getFixedContext(context), attrs, defStyleAttr, privateBrowsing);
    }

    public static Context getFixedContext(Context context) {
        return context.createConfigurationContext(new Configuration());
    }
}
```

Okay, no more crashes, good, BUT: I loaded the page which contains Select tag in html, and it didn't work if clicked on! Basically, android must open system dialog with Select's variables, but it doesn't...

Any ideas..?

Comment: do you want to use simple web view or LollipopFixedWebView??

Comment: @ShivamOberoi I want to use something that will work nicely. Okey, let's use LollipopFixedWebView

Answer (score 0):

Simply do-:

Change

```
<WebView
        tools:context=".Activities.WebViewActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"/>
```

to -:

```
<yourpackgename.LollipopFixedWebView
        tools:context=".Activities.WebViewActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"/>
```

and change in java file also

```
LollipopFixedWebView webview=findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: No, this solution blocks Select tag in html!

Comment: I mean that if I use this code app will not crash, but in my LollipopFixedWebView  I can't use <Select> in html. It's very important. Maybe I can handle click in Webview on <Select> and draw custom dialog instead native? Maybe there is some code I need to write to LollipopFixedWebView to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

check out my anwer in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025200/android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-webkit-webview/56168774#56168774)

in short: use fixed `Context` only on OS version on which default `Context` causes `InflateException`

```
private static Context getFixedContext(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) // Android Lollipop 5.0 & 5.1
        return context.createConfigurationContext(new Configuration());
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Good, but I suppose that issue with html's <Select> doesn't closed

Comment: @ snachmsm No, it doesn't... So, I've got a new issue. If I press <Select> in html app is crashing with this log: 

Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.

I suppose that system is trying to open SelectPopupDialog but it can't because of "null token". But I created LollipopFixedWebView with Activitiy's context!

Comment: @Progressier Any luck? I also faced this issue and used this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684229/1089841

Comment: Hello again, and yes, solution has been founded, but I don't know how did I do it... I remember, that in some cases it was Android failure, when some devices/systems doesn't have stable WebView component or Google Play Services